# Go difference in MySQL and MariaDB SELECT return type

Tags: mysql, go, mariadb, sqlx

When executing a `SELECT` query, and storing the results in a struct with a field of type `interface`, the resulting type differs between `int64` and `[]uint8` depending if the db I am using is a MySQL database, or MariaDB.

This is related to a previous question that I had asked (and was answered) : [Go SQL query inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833794/go-sql-query-inconsistency)

Given an interface as follows:

```
type Result struct {
    Afield string      `db:"A"`
    Bfield interface{} `db:"B"`
    Cfield string      `db:"C"`
    Dfield string      `db:"D"`
}
```

And database table:

```
A : VARCHAR(50)
B : INT
C : VARCHAR(50)
D : VARCHAR(50)
```

The query I would like to execute:

> SELECT A, B, C, D FROM table WHERE A="a"

How it is being executed:

```
db.Get(&result, `SELECT A, B, C, D FROM table WHERE A=?`, "a")
```

**The issue**

If being executed on a MySQL database, the type of `Bfield` is `int64` (desired), However if being executed on MariaDB, the type is instead `[]uint8`.

**Why is the type of Bfield different, depening on if the query is executed on a MySQL db or MariaDB?**

Potentially useful info:

db is of type: `*sqlx.DB`, then passed to function that executes the query, where db is type `Connection`.

```
// Connection is an interface for making queries.
type Connection interface {
    Exec(query string, args ...interface{}) (sql.Result, error)
    Get(dest interface{}, query string, args ...interface{}) error
    Select(dest interface{}, query string, args ...interface{}) error
}
```

I am using https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx

Comment: Presumably the protocol implementation is slightly different between the databases, and one transmits a byte array while the other sends an integer of some sort. Don't use the empty interface if you want type safety. The empty interface tells the driver "do whatever works best, I don't care about the type".

Comment: Thank you @Peter, I believe this was the issue. I have changed the type from `interface` to `*int` and my problems are resolved :)

Comment: `<snide-remark>`Another example of how 3rd party packages complicate access to MySQL`</snide-remark>`